# How to stub response from google oAuth token refresh in test?

Tags: unit-testing, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, wiremock

I send email with `com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail`;

```
public void sendEmail(Message message){
...
Message message = gmail.users().messages().send("me", message).execute();
...
}
```

My test triggers this method `sendEmail(Message message)` and because my user token is outdated `.execute()` also trigger token refresh:

`POST` `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`

How I can stub a response from `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`
Because the only way I find is to use WireMock and replace `https://oauth2.googleapis.com`
with `localhost` in properties.

But it will not work because oauth2 URL is hardcoded in library `com.google.api.services`

Are there any other ways to stub response from `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`?

Answer (score 1):

Where an SDK's base URL is hard-coded you can run WireMock as a forward proxy instead.

In this case you'd do this by setting `--enable-browser-proxying` or the code equivalent when you start WireMock. Then when you configure the GMail client's `HttpTransport` setting WireMock's host and port as the proxy.

See https://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/#running-as-a-browser-proxy for proxying details.